# My react select meant to be disabled doesn't display any default value

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, disabled-input

I'm still fairly new to react and I have some struggles finding why my defaultValueAttributes doesn't display anything:

```
<Select
    id="my_disabled_select"
    name="my_disabled_select"
    disabled
    defaultValue={connectedUser.options[0]}
/>
```

I have tried to display the `connectedUser.options[0]` in an InputLabel tag and the value is defined !

Does anyone know why this happens and how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the corresponding `MenuItem` child component so that the `Select` knows what to render.

Something like this should work:

```
<Select label="Age" defaultValue={10} disabled fullWidth>
   <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

See this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-material-ui-typescript-j6bpr8?file=components/App.tsx) stackblitz

Comment: I tried something around  that but got mixed up in the process, that was the solution, thank you :D